# Android PresetReverb not working (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

Doesn't add reverb effect to mediaplayer.

Added permission to the manifest. Checked if the device supports effects.

```
Check device:
D/Constraints: Loudness Enhancer, type: fe3199be-aed0-413f-87bb-11260eb63cf1
D/Constraints: Multichannel Downmix To Stereo, type: 381e49cc-a858-4aa2-87f6-e8388e7601b2
D/Constraints: Visualizer, type: e46b26a0-dddd-11db-8afd-0002a5d5c51b
D/Constraints: Insert Preset Reverb, type: 47382d60-ddd8-11db-bf3a-0002a5d5c51b
D/Constraints: Auxiliary Preset Reverb, type: 47382d60-ddd8-11db-bf3a-0002a5d5c51b
D/Constraints: Insert Environmental Reverb, type: c2e5d5f0-94bd-4763-9cac-4e234d06839e
D/Constraints: Auxiliary Environmental Reverb, type: c2e5d5f0-94bd-4763-9cac-4e234d06839e
D/Constraints: Volume, type: 09e8ede0-ddde-11db-b4f6-0002a5d5c51b
D/Constraints: Equalizer, type: 0bed4300-ddd6-11db-8f34-0002a5d5c51b
D/Constraints: Virtualizer, type: 37cc2c00-dddd-11db-8577-0002a5d5c51b
D/Constraints: Dynamic Bass Boost, type: 0634f220-ddd4-11db-a0fc-0002a5d5c51b
```

```
private var player: MediaPlayer ?= null
player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.r2);
val mReverb = PresetReverb(0, 0)
mReverb.preset = PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM
mReverb.enabled = true
player?.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.id)
player?.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f)
player?.start()
```

There are no error messages in Logcat